# Is OSGI a Good Choice?

Tags: java, spring, osgi

I'm currently in the middle of developing an internal facing CRM style application.  This needs to integrate with many external systems, and should degrade gracefully in the event those services are not available (by either the system being down, or the code which talks to it being disabled).

OSGI bundles, based on my current understanding, seem like the perfect way to make this happen.  We can shut down specific modules when maintenance is performed, and the code can perform actions differently when that service is unavailable.

My question is, with Spring apparently abandoning OSGI (this application uses Spring 4.0 heavily right now), is OSGI the right choice for this project?  Are there any alternative approaches I should consider?

Thanks

Comment: I've got good news and bad news for you. The good news is that yes, OSGi is a good choice, and that SpringSource abandoning or not abandoning it is irrelevant -- you can still use Spring with OSGi. The bad news is that your question is not suitable for StackOverflow since it is primarily opinion-based, so I have to vote to close it. Sorry!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apache Camel https://camel.apache.org/ could be a better choice, because it operates on a higher level than OSGI, which is what you might need, as SpaceTrucker already mentioned.
Camel is quite handy, when you need to integrate external systems.

Comment: Camel is based on OSGi, so this is like saying "Driving a Toyota Camry is a better choice than driving a car". It's still a car!

Comment: @NeilBartlett But it makes a difference if the car has a hand-crank starter or an electrical one. I think its worth to have a look at camel in the first place.

Comment: @SpaceTrucker Or you could say that Camel is like driving around in a big RV when all I need is a compact ;-)

Comment: Well, as luck would have it we're already using Apache Camel as our method of communication with some systems over JMS, so perhaps I should have a closer look at what other modules I could use from it to provide better modularization.

Answer (score 1):

OSGI isn't a swiss army knife for that kind of problem. Being loosely coupled to external services which may have downtimes is at a higher level than the problem osgi sovles. Have a look at [feature toogles](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Feature_toggle). You need to implement logic to switch the toggle if you determine a service has a downtime.

Comment: What, in your opinion, would be the tipping point that would mean I should probably use OSGI?

I did consider going down this feature toggle route (although I didn't call it that), but I thought perhaps OSGI might be a better approach.  As a side benefit it could also give us modules that other software could use down the track.

Comment: @Innominate I'm not able to exactly define that tipping point. It also has an influence what other requirements there are. And you already said modularization is one of them. I would aggree with tomix000 to have a look at camel.